# как посчитать сумму в многомерном массиве

Tags: php, массивы

Как посчитать сумму в многомерном массиве 5+3+4?

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [number] => 5
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [number] => 3
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [number] => 4
        )

)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если из готовых функций php, сначала можно сделать массив одномерный с помощью `array_column`, а потом посчитать сумму. Вот один из способов:

```
echo array_sum(array_column($arr, 'number'))
```

Comment: `array_walk_recursive` можно еще приделать в случае в случае более сложно структуры, либо `array_reduce` для суммирования